# Is it possible to transfer my Wattpad books to my Kindle?

Tags: kindle, kindle-app, send-to-kindle

Kindle model:

6" Glare-Free Touchscreen Display, Wi-Fi

[Amazon Link](http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00KDRQ2RU)

I can also live with a workaround for downloading them locally as a pdf and sending them through send-to-kindle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some Wattpad files are epub format and other are jad format and the latter may be more of an issue though I did find a number of on-line converter claiming to be able to convert them - preferably to epub as I found that reading pdfs on the Kindle was hard work because they are not re-paginated or re-flowed to match your screen size.

Personally I would suggest using [Calibre E-Book Manager](http://calibre-ebook.com/) for storing all & managing all of your ebooks.  If you store them in sensible formats like epub it can convert them to a number of formats including mobi for you and upload them to your Kindle *and a large number of other devices* via USB.

Comment: Stave, could you elaborate , please? I just discovered Wattpad and only read on Kindle, so it seems like I have to learn how to export, or find a Calibre plug-in. Do you know where I can find the Wattpad files on a Windows laptop?

Comment: @Mawg on a laptop Wattpad files are online at https://www.wattpad.com/ or IIRC can be downloaded to a mobile app, getting the files downloaded to PC  seems more complex.

Comment: Then I will do it the roundabout way. If they are on my Android, I can get them to my PC. Thanks, Steve

Comment: Please I do I get Wattpad book or access Wattpad from my kindle to read? I have Wattpad app on my iPhone also have a laptop if it’s better to access it that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FanFicFare Calibre Addon to download and update your wattpads.
https://github.com/JimmXinu/FanFicFare

Answer (score 0):

I use this free extension browser, and it sends the books straight to my kindle :) https://wattpad.xstudio.digital/index.html#how-it-works